# Как в массиве JavaScript перечислить список массивов и потом объединить их?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Сразу к делу!
Пример:

### 1.Есть массивы:

```
let arr1 = ["el1","el2","el3"];
let arr2 = ["el4","el5","el6"];
let arr3 = ["el7","el8","el9"];
let arrUsingInEx = [];
```

### 2. Перечисление массивов:

```
let allArrs = ["arr1", "arr2", "arr3"]
```

### 3. Вопрос: как прочитать все массивы и объединить в один?

*что-то типа этого чтобы было*

```
for (let i=0;i < allArrs.lenght;i++) {
    arrUsingInEx.push(i);
}
```

Ситуация: у меня на странице чекбоксы, у каждого есть name  с названием соответствующего массива. Надо если чекбокс выбран, массив сливать в кучку. Может есть получше решение.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: `let arrUsingInEx = arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `.concat();` тогда не потребуется перечислять массивы: `let allArrs = ["arr1", "arr2", "arr3"]` и затем ходить по ним через foreach, а сможете сразу их объединять.

Подробнее:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

```js
/* без перебора массива */
let arr1 = ["el1","el2","el3"];
let arr2 = ["el4","el5","el6"];
let arr3 = ["el7","el8","el9"];
let arrUsingInEx = [];
arrUsingInEx = arrUsingInEx.concat(arr1, arr2, arr3);
console.log(arrUsingInEx);
```

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, правильно ли я понял суть вопроса, но вот пример с объектами:

```js
var arrays = {
  arr1: ["q", "w", "e"],
  arr2: ["a", "s", "d"],
  arr3: ["z", "x", "c"]
}

var arrUsingInEx = {};
var output = document.querySelector('#output');

document.body.addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
  if (!target.name && target.type != 'checkbox') return;

  if (target.checked) arrUsingInEx[[target.name]] = arrays[target.name];
  if (!target.checked) delete arrUsingInEx[[target.name]];

  output.innerText = Object.values(arrUsingInEx);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="arr1">
<input type="checkbox" name="arr2">
<input type="checkbox" name="arr3">

<div id="output"></div>
```